# Filtering out values from a C# Generic Dictionary

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, filtering

I have a C# dictionary, `Dictionary<Guid, MyObject>` that I need to be filtered based on a property of `MyObject`.

For example, I want to remove all records from the dictionary where `MyObject.BooleanProperty = false`. What is the best way of acheiving this?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Since Dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Key, Value>>`, you can just use [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
var matches = dictionary.Where(kvp => !kvp.Value.BooleanProperty);
```

To recreate a new dictionary if you need it, use the [`ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

Comment: Ensure you have System.Linq using statement included at the top.

Comment: With this way, your dictionary turns into IEnumerable

Answer (score 151):

If you don't care about creating a new dictionary with the desired items and throwing away the old one, simply try:

```
dic = dic.Where(i => i.Value.BooleanProperty)
         .ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

If you can't create a new dictionary and need to alter the old one for some reason (like when it's externally referenced and you can't update all the references:

```
foreach (var item in dic.Where(item => !item.Value.BooleanProperty).ToList())
    dic.Remove(item.Key);
```

Note that `ToList` is necessary here since you're modifying the underlying collection. If you change the underlying collection, the enumerator working on it to query the values will be unusable and will throw an exception in the next loop iteration. `ToList` caches the values before altering the dictionary at all.

Comment: I was wondering what parameters I needed to pass in the ToDictionary method. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use the [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx) where clause:

```
var filtered = from kvp in myDictionary
               where !kvp.Value.BooleanProperty
               select kvp
```

Answer (score 7):

```
    public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Where<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> instance, Func<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Enumerable.Where(instance, predicate)
                         .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
    }
```

Comment: this should def be the selected answer

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general solution, working not only for boolean properties of the values.

**Method**

Reminder: Extension methods must be placed in static classes. Dont forget the `using System.Linq;` statement at the top of the source file.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a filtered copy of this dictionary, using the given predicate.
    /// </summary>
    public static Dictionary<K, V> Filter<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dict,
            Predicate<KeyValuePair<K, V>> pred) {
        return dict.Where(it => pred(it)).ToDictionary(it => it.Key, it => it.Value);
    }
```

**Usage**

Example:

```
    var onlyWithPositiveValues = allNumbers.Filter(it => it.Value > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the following extension method for my project which allows you to filter an IDictionary.

```
public static IDictionary<keyType, valType> KeepWhen<keyType, valType>(
    this IDictionary<keyType, valType> dict,
    Predicate<valType> predicate
) {
    return dict.Aggregate(
        new Dictionary<keyType, valType>(),
        (result, keyValPair) =>
        {
            var key = keyValPair.Key;
            var val = keyValPair.Value;

            if (predicate(val))
                result.Add(key, val);

            return result;
        }
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
IDictionary<int, Person> oldPeople = personIdToPerson.KeepWhen(p => p.age > 29);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope it fit your needs.

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new();
d.Add("Product", "SELECT * FROM PRODUCT");
d.Add("Order", "SELECT * FROM ORDER");
d.Add("Customer", "SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");
    
var x = d.Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "Order")
   .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value)
   .FirstOrDefault();
if(x.Key != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"{x.Value}"); //this should return "SELECT * FROM ORDER";
}
```