# Get keys as List<> from Dictionary for certain values

Tags: c#, linq

While similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131648/filtering-out-values-from-a-c-generic-dictionary) which gave me the LINQ for part of my problem, I'm missing something that seems like it must be obvious to avoid the last step of looping through the dictionary.

I have a Dictionary and I want to get a List of keys for just the items for which the value is true. Right now I'm doing this:

```
Dictionary<long,bool> ItemChecklist;
...


var selectedValues = ItemChecklist.Where(item => item.Value).ToList();

List<long> values = new List<long>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<long,bool> kvp in selectedValues) {
   values.Add(kvp.Key);
}
```

Is there any way I can go directly to a `List<long>` without doing that loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it in a single statement:

```
var values = ItemChecklist.Where(item => item.Value).Select(item => item.Key).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using [`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx):

```
List<long> result = ItemChecklist.Where(kvp => kvp.Value)
                                 .Select(kvp => kvp.Key)
                                 .ToList();
```