# Using Linq to filter out certain Keys from a Dictionary and return a new dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to figure out a linq query that will filter out a list of keys from a Dictionary and return a new filtered out dictionary

```
var allDictEnteries = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                     {
                                         {"Key1", "Value1"},
                                         {"Key2", "Value2"},
                                         {"Key3", "Value3"},
                                         {"Key4", "Value4"},
                                         {"Key5", "Value5"},
                                         {"Key6", "Value6"}
                                     };
var keysToBeFiltered = new List<string> {"Key1", "Key3", "Key6"};
```

The new dictionary should only contain the following entries

```
"Key2", "Value2"
"Key4", "Value4"
"Key5", "Value5"
```

I don't want to make a copy of the original dictionary and do Dictionary.Remove, I am thinking there might be and efficient way than that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131648/filtering-out-values-from-a-c-sharp-generic-dictionary

Comment: You're going to make a new dictionary anyway.  Create a copy of the original dictionary and use `Dictionary.Remove()`. It's an O(1) operation, and the entire thing is O(n) where n is the number of "keysToBeFiltered."  I doubt you're going to get better than that.

Answer (score 17):

You can filter the original dictionary, and use `ToDictionary` on the result:

```
var keysToBeFiltered = new HashSet<string> {"Key1", "Key3", "Key6"};
var filter = allDictEnteries
    .Where(p => !keysToBeFiltered.Contains(p.Key))
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, that is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @RamGopal If the answer works for you, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark outline next to the answer to indicate that you are not looking for alternative answer, and to get a brand new badge on Stack Overflow.