# Using Linq to filter out certain Keys from a Dictionary and return a new dictionary2

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Related to this question: [Using Linq to filter out certain Keys from a Dictionary and return a new dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10907344/using-linq-to-filter-out-certain-keys-from-a-dictionary-and-return-a-new-diction)

I got a control for a auto-complete that uses dictionary. Scenario was every word in my RichTextBox (to serve as code-editor) will automatically add in my list of autocomplete. Like if I type the word "asdasdasd" in RichTextBox , the word "asdasdasd" will automatically be added in my auto-complete .

using this code:

```
private IEnumerable<AutocompleteItem> BuildList()
{
    //find all words of the text
    var words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var keysToBeFiltered = new HashSet<string> { "Do", "Not" };
    var filter = words.Where(p => !keysToBeFiltered.Contains(p.Key))
                      .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtb_JS.Text, @"\b\w+\b"))
        filter[m.Value] = m.Value;

    //foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtb_JS.Text, @"^(\w+)([=<>!:]+)(\w+)$"))
        //filter[m.Value] = m.Value;

    foreach (var word in filter.Keys)
    {
        yield return new AutocompleteItem(word);
    }
}
```

Now the word "Do" and "Not" are still included to auto-complete using the code above. Also when my form loads, a specific default script appears that must be there all the time. So i can't change it.

Two possible solutions I have do to fix this:
1. don't allow those default words used in default script add in my autocomplete when form loads.(make list of words that prevent from adding into my list)
2. detect the line that has commented "//" or "/*" and prevent words from it to add in my dictionary.

Hope you can help me. Please tell me if I need to revise my question and I'll revise/update it ASAP.

main_Q:

how to prevent adding commented words from richtextbox (line that starts with // or /*) into autocomplete

Comment: how to prevent adding commented words from richtextbox (line that starts with // or /*) into autocomplete

Comment: What is the reason of your second Regex?

Comment: I'll add that your problem is perhaps wrong: `//` comments from that point onward. `something // somethingelse` only `somethingelse` is commented. `/*` is the same, but multiline, so until you get a `*/` it's still commented.

Comment: @xanatos ill commented second regex sorry my bad ... 2. then all words  inside /* and */ shouldnt be add in richtextbox

Comment: @Elegiac And then there are strings... `string foo = "// something"`; the `//` isn't a comment. Doing it correctly is a pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your problem in the following line:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtb_JS.Text, @"\b\w+\b"))
        filter[m.Value] = m.Value;
```

With **"\b\w+\b"** regex, you add all words in your RichTextBox control to your *filter* variable.

So, you must change your code in that line *for prevent from adding your unwanted keywords*. Please check the following:

```
private IEnumerable<AutocompleteItem> BuildList()
{
    //find all words of the text
    bool bolFindMatch = false;
    var words = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    var keysToBeFiltered = new HashSet<string> { "Do", "Not" };
    var filter = words.Where(p => !keysToBeFiltered.Contains(p.Key))
                      .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtb1.Text, @"\b\w+\b"))
    {
        foreach (string hs in keysToBeFiltered)
        {
            if (Regex.Matches(m.Value, @"\b" + hs + @"\b").Count > 0)
            {
                bolFindMatch = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!bolFindMatch)
        {
            filter[m.Value] = m.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            bolFindMatch = false;
        }
    }

    //foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(rtb_JS.Text, @"^(\w+)([=<>!:]+)(\w+)$"))
        //filter[m.Value] = m.Value;

    foreach (var word in filter.Keys)
    {
        yield return new AutocompleteItem(word);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do not you just check weather the string starts with `"//"` or `"/*"` before you do your processing

```
    string notAllowed1 = @"//";
    string notAllowed2 = @"/*";
    var contains = false;
    foreach(string line in rtb_JS.Lines)
    {
       if (line.StartsWith(notAllowed2) || !line.StartsWith(notAllowed1))
       {
         contains = true;
         break
       }
   }
//else do nothing
```

**update 2 with Linq**

```
    var contains = rtb_JS.Lines.ToList()
                  .Count( line => line.TrimStart().StartsWith(notAllowed2) || 
                   line.TrimStart().StartsWith(notAllowed1)) > 0 ;


if(!contains)
{
   //do your logic
}
```

Comment: I would probably `TrimStart` `rtb_JS`... And perhaps it has to be split into lines (it isn't clear from the question if `rtb_JS` is multiline or singleline

Comment: i think .startswith only indicate the index of the text and not the index of perline

Comment: then xanatos idea is perfect, do a trim and then split it in multilines and check for each line weather it starts with // or /* or not

Comment: @xanatos can you help me with that sir?

Comment: @Anand string does not contains a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found

Comment: @Anand i think the //do you logic was my main problem here :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
var filter = Regex.Matches(rtb_JS.Text, @"\b\w+\b")
                  .OfType<Match>()
                  .Where(m=>!keysToBeFiltered.Any(x=>x == m.Value))
                  .ToDictionary(m=>m.Value,m=>m.Value);
```

It's strange that your `Dictionary` has `Key`and `Value` as the same values in an entry?

Comment: an item with the same key has already been added pointing to that code