# How to filter NSDictionary by value and create new NSDictionary from that?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, filtering

I have a list of dates in a format `yyyyMMdd` as `long`. I've created dictionary with **key** `yyyyMMdd` and **value** `yyyyMM` (as `NSString`). I need to filter that `NSDictionary` (by **`value`**) and create a new one form that. How to do that?

REMARK: I suppose that this is duplicate, but I can not figure out how to do that.

**EDIT:** 
I don't understand why my question is marked as **duplicate** with questions solving my problem is C#?
As I know (my knowledge in objective-C is limited) the syntax is very different. Also I don't know about `linq` or `lambdas` in objective-C.

Comment: If you already think, that this is a duplicate, why don't you use the search function in the first place?

Comment: I already used Google and search function, @d4Rk, but I can not understand how to do it. I paste that remark for that reason. I already get -1. I try to do it right. Other option is to iterate through `NSDictionary` and compare `value` with filter string, but I think is is very noobish. But if I did not find other solution I will go that way.

Comment: What about this (my first result on google)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131648/filtering-out-values-from-a-c-sharp-generic-dictionary

Comment: I am using iOS (objective-C), @d4Rk, not C#! I don't understand. I think that syntax is very different. If I was in C# I will use **linq** for example. As far as I now there is no **linq** in objective-C.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake.. ;) In Objc it's a bit tougher to find a solution.. but I'll take a look for you.

Comment: It may be easier to help you, if you could provide some information on, why you need all this transformations (list to dict to dict?)

Comment: Yes, @d4Rk. I need to make custom calendar control in which I need to show some dates marked. Initially I have all dates which have to be marked (I receive them from Web service). I need to filter each time I have new month - so I created One dictionary with all dates and in the value I put the month info (using `yyyyMM` notation). So when I switch to new month I need to filter data for that particular month to show count at the top and to mark appropriate cells.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this (including the one you consider noobish). Here's one:

```
NSArray* keys = [dict keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop){
    // return YES or NO depending on whether the value (in "obj") passes your test
}];
NSDictionary* newDict = [dict dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
```

Be warned that `-dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:`, when applied to a dictionary, can do something unexpected for keys starting with "@". That's because it's implemented in terms of `-valueForKey:` and `NSDictionary`'s implementation of that method treats such keys specially. Shouldn't matter for the case you described.

Comment: 10x, @Ken Thomases. I mean "noobish" because I think that there must be another way except iteration. I don't mean that it is improper, but I hope for more elegant (in my point) solution.

Comment: How can one check items on a list without iterating? At least a method of `NSDictionary` iterates. Put Ken's method in a category and you get the same result.

Comment: For example, @Amin Negm-Awad, filtering (with predicates). May be it iterates inside, but you don't iterate yourself. This was my logic. I don't claim that it is correct.

Comment: Not maybe it iterates, it iterates definitely. How can one check predicates on items of a list without iterating? Putting the code into a category makes it a part of the class.

Comment: Sorry, @Amin Negm-Awad, my English is not so good and I obviously can not explain myself. I mean that I want shorthand command - yes predicate iterates (but it does it behind the scenes). I mean that I don't want to write `for each` loop to iterate myself and to make comparison. In code like: `NSArray *data = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"foo" forKey:@"BAR"]];    
NSArray *filtered = [data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(BAR == %@)", @"foo"]];` I don't do that. May be I don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //old dictionary stores @{date: string} ,where data = NSDate; string = NSString from NSDate
 NSMutableArray * storedValues = [[oldDictionary allValues]mutableCopy];
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF > %@",[NSDate date]];
 NSArray *sortedArray = [storedValues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


  NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  for(NSDate *date in sortedArray) {
      NSArray *keys = [oldDictionary allKeysForObject:date];
      NSString *key = keys.firstObject;
     [newDictionary setObject:date forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So I'm still not 100% sure about what you want to do, and why you want to do it this way.

But check this out:

```
// create a new dict for this example, you can just use ur existing one
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"201506", @"20150601",
                                                                  @"201505", @"20150501", nil];

NSArray *resultArray = [[dict allValues] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", @"201506"]];

// testing the output
NSLog(@"%@", resultArray);
```

You don't have a dictionary in the end, but an array with your filtered values from the dictionary. Maybe you'll have to adjust the predicate for your needs and put the resultArray stuff back into a dictionary, but I've no idea, how your result should look like.