# Filter generic list with generic dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to filter with LINQ a list of this type `List<Dictionary<String, Object>>` but I can't find the way.

I have this code:

```
private List<Dictionary<String, Object>> ValidateScenarioProductItemData(List<Dictionary<String, Object>> pList)
{
    foreach (var tItem in pList)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tItem["IsInternal"].ToString()))
        {
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var item in tPeriods)
            {
                i++;
                var tHasSails = tCycleProductItemSales.Where(
                        CPIS => CPIS.CycleId == Convert.ToInt32(tItem["CycleId"].ToString()) &&
                        CPIS.ProductItemId == Convert.ToInt32(tItem["ProductItemId"].ToString()) && 
                        CPIS.PeriodId == Convert.ToInt32(item.Id.ToString()));
                if (tHasSails.Count() == 0)
                {
                    tItem[string.Format("Datasource{0}Id", i)] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return pList;
}
```

I want to filter `pList` in the foreach to avoid by the Key `IsInternal` to avoid asking the next if and to avoid unnecessary calls.

I have tried this but it does not work:
[Filtering out values from a C# Generic Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131648/filtering-out-values-from-a-c-sharp-generic-dictionary)

Comment: What is `tPeriods`? And just so I get this right: You want to convert the code you have to linq?

Comment: Not answering your question but using `tHasSails.Count` will enumerate the whole collection. If you are only interested if the collection has any elements use `IEnumerable..Any` instead.

Comment: Sorry to all pPeriods is a global value that i need

Comment: This is very inefficient code...O(n^2) and lots of boxing/unboxing...also a list of dictionary is not very useful (search is now O(n))...try to convert (if possible) the keys of the dictionary to account for the variation in the list....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you iterate through 2 data sources I think you cannot join it into 1 LINQ.
The best you can do is to join the first condition to the .Where clause

```
private List<Dictionary<String, Object>> ValidateScenarioProductItemData(List<Dictionary<String, Object>> pList)
{
    var tPeriods = new List<dynamic>();
    var tCycleProductItemSales = new List<dynamic>();
    foreach (var tItem in pList.Where(x=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x["IsInternal"].ToString())))
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in tPeriods)
        {
            i++;
            var tHasSails = tCycleProductItemSales.Where(CPIS => CPIS.CycleId == Convert.ToInt32(tItem["CycleId"].ToString()) && CPIS.ProductItemId == Convert.ToInt32(tItem["ProductItemId"].ToString()) && CPIS.PeriodId == Convert.ToInt32(item.Id.ToString()));
            if (!tHasSails.Any())
            {
                tItem[string.Format("Datasource{0}Id", i)] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return pList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right you need to filter out dictionary item where key is "IsInternal" and the object is not null, then how about this -

```
var filteredList = pList.Where(d => d.Keys.Contains("IsInternal") && d.Values != null);
```