# How to filter dictionary and get the keys from the database table

Tags: c#, dictionary, filter

I have stored multiple values in the config and now I want to compare those values with the ones which are coming from the DB. There is a method that consists of a dictionary which I want to get the property to check against. Which is AccountNumber?

**How can I filer a dictionary to get the key and use it to check if the value exists or not?**

```
public FinancialDocument(FinancialDocumentMetadata metaData, Uri url)
    {
        MetaData = metaData;
        DocumentUrl = url;
    }

  **Model**
  public class FinancialDocumentMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
        --
        --
        --
   }
```

This is the configurations values

```
   <add key="AccountNumbers" value="A,B,C,D,E,F"/>
```

Getting the accounts store from the config

```
      string[] accountArray = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AccountNumbers"].Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
       List<string> accountlist = new List<string>(accountArray);
```

This is the method that got a dictionary of files. I want to check a property(AccountNumber) from  FinancialDocument to check against

```
   private void Generate(Document targetDocument, Dictionary<FinancialDocument, PdfDocument> files)
    {
            //Want to check against the accounts numbers, if exists.
            if (accountlist.Contains("files.xxx.accountnumber"))//Not sure how i can filter the AccountNumber field to check against.
            {
               --
            }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure how what excactly you want to do. You can use linq take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131648/filtering-out-values-from-a-c-sharp-generic-dictionary. Where excactly is your problem? It is not clear what you want to do with the dicitonary

Comment: I want the check values coming from AccountNumber. Config values will have few accounts that i want to check from, AccountNumber got all the values. I accountNumber 'A' exist, I will continue with my logic

Comment: Ok you pass a Dictionary of `<FinancialDocument, PdfDocument>` -> `<TKey,TValue>`. In which object the AccountNumber is in, how to get from the `FinancialDocument` to `FinancialDocumentMetadata`? Please update your question and provide us full details of your model and your end result.

Comment: I guess it must be something like this  Key.MetaData.AccountNumber

Comment: @JuniorLinq: yes, sorry, I forgot `.MetaData` in my answer, now included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do and the best way to do it. Your question is not very detailed. If you want to compare your files to the list of accountNumbers, this might be a solution:

```
private void Generate(Document targetDocument, Dictionary<FinancialDocument, PdfDocument> files)
{

       foreach(var file in files)
       {
             if(accountList.Contains(file.Key.MetaData.AccountNumber))
             {
                     // your logic here
                     var pdfDocument = file.Value;
             }
       }

}
```